# MATLAB - How to measure mean intensity of a circular area in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want the mean intensity of an image, not the whole but only in a certain region of interest. This happens to be circular in shape and I know details of its radius and position.

Just inside the circular ROI (circle not drawn, using the radius and position). I dont want to mask the image and delete the outsides because that'll add unnecessary datapoints to the average.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498419/mean-value-in-a-sphere/44513251 , The answer by Siva Srinivas Kolukula would probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean indexing

% creating the image:

```
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(1:100);
r = 23; x0 = 45; y0 = 67;
pixelsInSphere = ((xx-x0).^2 + (yy-y0).^2 < r);
im = pixelsInSphere.*(128+10*randn(size(yy)));
figure; imagesc(im);
```

% calculating the mean of the pixels using boolean indexing:

```
m = mean(im(pixelsInSphere));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Indicator function which given a position of pixel `(i, j)` it will say whether it is inside the ROI or not.

Loop over all the pixel in the image.
Sum the pixels which are in the ROI according to the indicator.